# Getting multiple values in multiple select tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple  tags in an HTML file and I'm having problems knowing the value of each one at the same time.

```js
  function knowAllValues(){
    var color_element = document.getElementById("color");
    var size_element = document.getElementById("size");

    var color_text = color_element.options[color_element.selectedIndex].text;
    var size_text = size_element.options[size_element.selectedIndex].text;
    
    window.alert(color_text + " - " + size_text);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
  <select id="color">
    <option value="1">Op1</option>
    <option value="2">Op2</option>
    <option value="3">Op3</option>
  </select>

  <select id="size">
    <option value="1">S</option>
    <option value="2">M</option>
    <option value="3">L</option>
    <option value="4">XL</option>
  </select>

  <button type="button" onclick="knowAllValues()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you getting in the alert? seems like its working fine. are you inserting the script properly in your html?

Comment: Seems to work just fine to me https://jsfiddle.net/hhy06unf/ , you can describe more what is your problem ?

Comment: I made the snippet work using your code without adding or removing anything.

Comment: Do you have many time this select combinaison in your page ? If so, your problem may be due to duplicate `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not quite sure what you're looking for, but it seems like you might want to investigate how to use a [for loop in Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).  This will let you iterate through all of your options.

Additionally, you should check out jQuery.  You can iterate through all of your option values by doing something like this:

```
$('#color option').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ck82m32g/)

Either way, you need to iterate through your options, whether with javascript or jquery.  Each time you iterate through, you can store it to a variable and use it to display all of them at once.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all... OP did not used any loop and its code works. If OP has a real problem, this is due something else.